# Dynamically loading multiple select box using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

In my CodeIgniter view page , I want to display a searchable select box .And I can manipulate any number of copies of searchable select box using a add button . The searchable select box data filled by ajax call .This is my requirement ,I am adding  a picture below to clarify my problem.

[image: My requirement picture]

I am  providing my CodeIgniter controller function below that handles ajax request:

```
public function ajax_load()
{

    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request())
    {

        $labtests = $this->Laboratory_service_model->getLabTests(); //gets result_array()

        if (!empty($labtests))
        {

            $data['return'] = true;
            $data['a'] = $labtests;
            
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
        else
        {
            $data['return'] = false;
            $data['message'] = 'cant get data from table';
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $data['return'] = false;
        $data['message'] = 'Ajax request not getting';
        echo json_encode($data);
    }



}
```

And my JavaScript file provide here :

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: surl + 'LabServices/ajax_load',

        success: function (data)
        {
            var ndata = JSON.parse(data);


            if (ndata.return == true)
            {
                var myOptions = ndata.a;

                var mySelect = $('#mySelect');

                myOptions.forEach(function(data)
                {
                    mySelect.append(
                        $('<option></option>').val(data.id).html(data.name)
                    );
                });

            }
            else if (ndata.return == false)
            {
                $('.error').text(ndata.message);
            }
            else
            {
                $('.error').text('something went wrong');
            }

        },
        error: function ()
        {
            $('.error').text('something went wrong');
        }

    });
```

I already fetched data from controller using ajax and created a searchable select box ,with the help of select2 library in CodeIgniter. But I dont know how to dynamically manipulate select box with buttons .Please give me a solution friends..

And my view page section is :

```
                <a class="col-md-6 mb-3 htmlitems">
                    <label>Lab Tests</label>
                    <div class="form-control ">
                        <select id="mySelect" class="" style="width: 100%;" name="tests">

                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <a id="" class="btn btn-danger add_spec"> + </a>
                </div>
```

Thanks in advance
Shinoy

Comment: where is code for adding new select-box ?

Comment: The code for adding select box is residing inside ajax function .In my view page you can see a select tag ,which has id = mySelect.By using that id I can fill  option(select options) from js file.But the select tag cant load thats the problem.The code which I provided above is incomplete .I need help.And thank you in advance.

Comment: so you just need to create selectbox like first one when you click on `+` ? am i right?

Comment: Yes .That is I wanted .Any suggestion on this problem or answer will be very helpful .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your select option will be same so onclick of `add_spec` instead of calling ajax to retrieve options again you can just `clone` options of already added select and then add this `cloned` to your htmls . Then, intialize it using `find('select:last').select2();`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("#mySelect").select2();
$(".add_spec").click(function() {
  var options = $(".htmlitems:first").find("[name=tests]").clone(); //get select and clone it
  //generate html and add options inside select
  var result = '<div class="col-md-6 mb-3 htmlitems"><label>Lab Tests</label><div class="form-control "><select class="new_added" style="width: 100%;" name="tests">' + $(options).html() + '</select><button class="remove">-</button></div>'
  $(result).appendTo("#result") //add generated htmls 
  $('#result').find('select:last').select2(); //initialize it

});
//on click of remove
$(document).on("click", ".remove", function() {
  $(this).closest(".htmlitems").remove() //get closest div remove it
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">
  <div class="col-md-6 mb-3 htmlitems">
    <label>Lab Tests</label>
    <div class="form-control ">
      <select id="mySelect" class="" style="width: 100%;" name="tests">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <a id="" class="btn btn-danger add_spec"> + </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Swati ,The above answer is very helpful and with minor modification I can achieve the adding more select box functionality in my web app. But I need to  include another button ( - ) at the end of each newly created select box (as mentioned in the question )  and I wish I could remove the select box using that button.Am lookin forward your answer .

Comment: Hi, sorry i didn't saw that  . Updated my answer :)

Comment: Am very thankful to you .Because of your answer I can move forward my programming wall. I also look forward your help in future too. Thank you again @Swati..

Comment: Unfortunately the above answer not work properly , When I add  new select box,  previously created select box values are changing to first option in  option tag .Any suggestion. And also when I click  (-) button to remove select box , the select box deletion occurs from top and some point it delete from bottom.

Comment: I am not seeing any such behaviour in above demo code .. can you create js fiddle to show that behaviour ?

Comment: okay wait ,am new to this fiddle. I will get back to you

Comment: Can u support me directly via remote desktop or share my project module with GitHub .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226853/discussion-between-swati-and-shinoy-p-b).

Comment: .look chat for  details @Swati